# Using setattr between QThreads in PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a program that contains two main classes:

- A GUI class that inherits from QWidget, and has several user input and output fields (graphs, spin boxes etc.)
- A Serial Monitor class that inherits from QObject and contains various loops for continuously polling serial attached devices in accordance with a set of parameters (sample period, polling commands, etc.)

An instance of the Serial Monitor class is created from within the GUI class and moved to a secondary thread like so:

```
    # Create Serial monitor instance in this thread
    self.serial_monitor = Serial_Monitor(
        formatter=self.poll,
        prompt="2 poll\n")

    # Create a secondary QThread to run the serial monitor
    self.serial_thread = QThread()

    # Move the serial monitor to the secondary thread and start
    self.serial_monitor.moveToThread(self.serial_thread)
    self.serial_thread.start()
```

My question arises when trying to directly pass the output of user interface items (spin boxes, buttons etc.) to variables in the Serial Monitor. My main aims are:

- I want to avoid creating several pyqtSlot functions in the Serial Monitor just to set each variable, as it makes adding further variables a faff and bloats the code.
- I would also like to keep all setting of Serial Monitor variables in the correct thread, rather than setting them in the GUI command thread.

---

My initial solution to directly setting variables from the GUI was this:

```
self.set_box_period.valueChanged.connect(
        lambda val: setattr(self.serial_monitor, "sample_period", val))
```

It avoids creating any new methods in the Serial Monitor, and appears to set the variables just fine, however I am not sure if it is "thread safe", and further more am not sure how to find out.

After some digging I found out that you can re-implement the __setattr__ method within a class like so:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    """
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Re-implementation of "getattr" method to correctly wire up to slots
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    """
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    self.logger.info(F"Set {name} to {value}")
```

The logging output indicates that every Serial Monitor variable is set within the Serial Monitor thread, so this solution does work, however I am not sure if it is necessary.

To sum up, do I need to worry about re-implementing __setattr__ in my Serial Monitor class, or is my initial lambda implementation perfectly safe to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show exactly how you are connecting the `__setattr__` slot to the signals. Also, I don't see any evidence that the logger output will show you which thread `__setattr__` is called in. From the code you've shown so far, the setting of the variables is *not* thread-safe. However, in itself, this doesn't really mean very much unless the variable data is shared between multiple worker threads (rather than, say, a simple one-way communication between the main thread and one worker thread).

Comment: @ekhumoro The logger has been configured with `%(thread)d` in the formatter so all output messages have the thread included.
The middle section of my code is where I wire up a signal from `set_box_period` to `__seattr__`, although via a lambda so not sure how well that's working.

Comment: In that case, in itself, the `__setattr__` slot does not change anything. Can you please show some actual evidence that `__setattr__` is being called in the worker thread? You really need to provide a [mcve], otherwise it is just guesswork as to whether your program is thread-safe or not.